# Return number of rows php mvs

Tags: php, sql, arrays, rowcount

I am trying to return the number of results found on my page above an html table. I am using an mvc framework for the first time so it's very new to me how the process works.

My query works and displays the tabular results successfully, my issue is [probably] with the positioning of my return code?

I have included my code for reference;

**Model**

```
public function categoryView()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 
    b.id, 
    b.title,
    b.category, 
    FROM book
    WHERE status != 'Archive' AND category = :cat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15");

    $sth->bindValue(':cat', $_GET['category']);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // won't run when included
    return count($result); // won't run when included

    $all_books = array();

    foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $book) {       
        $all_books[$book->id] = new stdClass();
        $all_books[$book->id]->id = $book->id;
        $all_books[$book->id]->title = $book->title;
        $all_books[$book->id]->category = $book->cat_name;
    }
    return $all_books;
}
```

**View**

```
Found <?php echo count($result); ?> records
<table>
<?php
foreach ($this->books as $book) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$book->id.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$book->title.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$book->category.'</td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}     
?> 
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
function categoryView()
{
    $categoryView_model = $this->loadModel('Books');
    $this->view->books = $categoryView_model->categoryView();
    $this->view->render('books/categoryView');
}
```

I receive the error errors on my view page

```
Warning: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ... on line 51`
```

and

```
Found 
Notice: Undefined variable: result in ... on line 47
0 records
```

Line 47 contains `Found <?php echo count($result); ?> records`

Line 51 contains `foreach ($this->books as $book) { ... }`

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: How are the data passed from view to model and from model to view?

Comment: `$result` exists ONLY in your `categoryView()` method as a local variable, and will not be available anywhere else. And in your view, `$this->books` is obviously not an array, meaning `$this` is not object you think it is, or $this->books doesn't contain the results of your db operations.

Comment: ... and `return count($result);` from model ... breaks the function `$all_books` is never passed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, how should I remedy the situation? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these two lines

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // won't run when included
return count($result); // won't run when included
```

In your view change

```
Found <?php echo count($result); ?> records
```

to

```
Found <?php echo count($this->books); ?> records
```

The reason you have to do this is because you're storing the results returned from `categoryView()` into the `books` property of the view when you run the following line

```
$this->view->books = $categoryView_model->categoryView();
```

Note that the count will always be a maximum of 15. If you want to display the total # of found results you should issue a separate `select count(*)` without a `limit` clause.

Comment: @johnny_s see update, `$results` is not in scope in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It would help us a lot if you specified the framework. Honestly I have only worked in Zend as a php framework but over there you have to assign the property to your view:

```
   $this->view->property = $all_books; //or any other property
```

and to retrieve it in the view

```
  <?php echo $this->property; ?>
```

I find it hard to beleive that your MVC calls the function (action),which in zend needs to be named in a specific way, from the view and so uses a return. I an tell you one thing, your way of sending the variable to the view is wrong, the return must not be the correct way of sending it. Without your framework this is the only way I can help you in addition I would tell you to actually echo an isset f both variables and you will see my theory is right you are not sending the variables from the controller, action or function correctly

Comment: I am using php pdo. I have included my controller which renders the view. My query doesn't run when I include the $result or return (updated question with commented code). Thanks